# Rest API doesn't work in C# but succeeded in Postman

Tags: c#, rest, postman

Currently, I am consuming a service in postman to consult a specific endpoint, in postman the only thing I do is paste the URL in the request with parameters included, and it returns the content correctly, but when I do the same process from C#, it responds (OK200), but in data I get nothing.

This is the URL endpoint: https://citaconsular.es/onlinebookings/getwidgetconfigurations/?callback=jQuery21106986789352158271_1707334634680&type=default&publickey=2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037&lang=es&version=1246&src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.citaconsular.es%2Fes%2Fhosteds%2Fwidgetdefault%2F2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037%23services&srvsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fcitaconsular.es&_=1707334634682

This is my Postman case

[image]

And this is my c# petition, i'm using restSharp por this petition, I'm trying with `httpClient` as well

```cs
private static void FindAppointmentss()
{
    try
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://citaconsular.es");
        var request = new RestRequest("/onlinebookings/getservices/", Method.Get);
        request.AddQueryParameter("callback", "jQuery2110803503481037606_1707334189954");
        request.AddQueryParameter("type", "default");
        request.AddQueryParameter("publickey", "2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037");
        request.AddQueryParameter("lang", "es");
        request.AddQueryParameter("version", "1246");
        request.AddQueryParameter("src", "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.citaconsular.es%2Fes%2Fhosteds%2Fwidgetdefault%2F2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037%23services");
        request.AddQueryParameter("srvsrc", "https%3A%2F%2Fcitaconsular.es");
        request.AddQueryParameter("_", "1707334189957");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/javascript");

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            string content = response.Content;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No data content: " + response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I always get No data content

I tried to create a request from postman which was successful, as seen in the case description, I also tried to do it from c#, Nodejs and ReactJS.
From c# and Nodejs, the response was successful, but it did not return data, as, for example, the Postman case does.

The expected answer is the next text callback, its content is application/javascript

```json
callback=jQuery21106986789352158271_1707334634680({
    "WidgetConfiguration": {
        "any_agenda": "2",
        "registration_type": "2",
        "waiting_list": "0",
        "show_comments": "0",
        "mandatory_comments": "0",
        "min_service_to_enable_dropdown": "0",
        "template": "1",
        "captcha": "0",
        "payment_enable": false,
        "payments_gateways": {
            "stripe": false,
            "paypal": false,
            "redsys": false,
            "niubiz": false
        }
    },
    "WidgetLabel": []
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that you should be pre-escaping your query parameter values? `"https%3A%2F%2Fcitaconsular.es"`, won't `AddQueryParameter` escape the value for you?

Comment: You can use a network sniffer like Fiddler or Wireshark to view the final HTTP request sent by C# and compare that with Postman's request.

Comment: When you see: "No data content", what is the value of: `response.StatusCode` ?

Comment: response.StatusCode = 200

Comment: Using a debugger, you can see that `response.Content` is indeed empty, but `response.ResponseUri.Query` seems to contain the value you need.

Comment: `Response.ResponseUri.Query`, is not the value. the value is a JSON 

callback=jQuery21106986789352158271_1707334634680({
    "WidgetConfiguration": {
        "any_agenda": "2",
        "registration_type": "2",
        "waiting_list": "0"...

You can try this example in postman.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have an account to access https://www.citaconsular.es/,  There should be some documentation about that API (somewhere....)

Comment: Why is FindAppointmentss private? Also, spelling...rename to "FindAppointments"

Comment: It's only an example, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When I investigated your API request in Postman using the postman console, I found that the request is using a header called Referer.

```
    Referer: https://citaconsular.es/onlinebookings/getwidgetconfigurations/?callback=jQuery21106986789352158271_1707334634680&type=default&publickey=2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037&lang=es&version=1246&src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.citaconsular.es%2Fes%2Fhosteds%2Fwidgetdefault%2F2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037%23services&srvsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fcitaconsular.es&_=1707334634682
Host: www.citaconsular.es
```

I tried using it in Restsharp and I am getting content in the response. **Please use addheader called Refer**. Following is my code:

```
public void TestBooking()
{
 
     var restClient = new RestClient("https://citaconsular.es");
     var request = new RestRequest("/onlinebookings/getservices/");
     request.AddParameter("callback", "jQuery2110803503481037606_1707334189954");
     request.AddParameter("type", "default");
     request.AddParameter("publickey", "2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037");
     request.AddParameter("lang", "es");
     request.AddParameter("version", "1246");
     request.AddParameter("src", "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.citaconsular.es%2Fes%2Fhosteds%2Fwidgetdefault%2F2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037%23services");
     request.AddParameter("srvsrc", "https%3A%2F%2Fcitaconsular.es");
     request.AddParameter("_", "1707334189957");
     request.AddHeader("Referer", "https://citaconsular.es/onlinebookings/getwidgetconfigurations/?" +
         "callback=jQuery21106986789352158271_1707334634680&type=default&publickey=2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037&" +
         "lang=es&version=1246&src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.citaconsular.es%2Fes%2Fhosteds%2Fwidgetdefault%2F2535680773512eb064e273253a3ba5037%23" +
         "services&srvsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fcitaconsular.es&_=1707334634682");
 
     var response = restClient.Execute(request);
}
```

I've attached a screenshot.

Hope this resolves your query.[image][image]